# How to merge two columns (start date and end date) and create a timeline in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have columns from the database in the format(example)-

```
Id  | Begin timestamp  | End timestamp
001 | Thu,2/7/2019 9:05:36AM  | Thu,2/7/2019 9:06:01AM
```

I need to count the number of Id (count(Id)) within a certain time frame (example from 9:00-10:00AM). I want to make a plot in tableau with x-axis as the time axis and y-axis showing the count(Id).

For example, if both Id- 001 and 002 were online between 9:05:56- 9:06:10AM it will give me a trend graph line of count(id)=2 between that time frame.

Comment: If you can reshape your data to make it more transactional (one row for start, one row for end, for each session), then you can treat each row as a +1 (log in) or -1 (log out) and use the running sum of this value as your user count at any given time.

Comment: Adding to Andy's advice, you can use Tableau's reshape tool if your data is in excel. https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-10394

Comment: can you post more sample data?